# ImageMagick not working - <img alt="Missing" src="/images/medium/missing.png">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using paperclip + imagemagick but my images are not being correctly uploaded, and when I inspect the element it says: img alt="Missing" src="/images/medium/missing.png"

I have no idea why is it looking for the images on that path.

I am using Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0 and Windows 7, and given the research I have already done online I understand it can be tricky to get ImageMagick and paperclip properly working on this operating system.

This is what I have already done, nothing seems to be working yet:

1. Installed paperclip version 3.5.2.
2. Uninstalled and installed ImageMagick several times (tried static and dynamic versions... x86 and x64 and nothing)
3. Re-checked all the commands syntax
4. Added the ImageMagick path on development and production config.

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16'

1. Created a new rb file on config, initializers, called paperclip with the following:

require "paperclip"

Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16'

Paperclip.options[:swallow_stderr] = false

1. Restarted the pc, restarted the command prompt, restarted rails servers.

Nothing seems to have changed anything, my images still appear as broken links and the error I am getting is the same.

Could you please help me figure it out?

Thanks

A.-

Comment: I think that you need install ImageMagick with all delegates. There are brew formulas around there but I don't know how to do it on windows. Sorry. Try googling install ImageMagick with all delegates / dependencies on windows.

Comment: I had the same issue I fixed it by not installing image magic via the source but via sudo apt-get install imagemagick in Ubuntu. It is a imagemagick issue.